# Position text over image along with folloing DIV

Tags: html, css

I have managed to position a div over image, but div and paragraph after that is overlapping on top of image. Idealy i would like to have it after image.

http://jsfiddle.net/tp82y04n/

HTML code:

```
<div id="container">
<img id="image" src="http://www.noao.edu/image_gallery/images/d4/androa.jpg"/>
<div id="form"><input type="text" /></div>
</div>
<div id="main-content"><p>Test paragraph</p></div>
```

CSS styles:

```
div#container {
position: relative;
}
img#image {
position: absolute;
}
#form {
position: absolute;
top: 150px;
left: 100px;
}
#main-content p {
color: #fff;
}
#main-content{
overflow: hidden;
position:relative;
}
```

I would like to have something like this.
[image]

Comment: remove this stle img#image {position: absolute; }

Answer (score 2):

I have created a basic version of the same here http://jsfiddle.net/ukv4chmg/1/

Essentially, I placed the `input` in a separate division with some background; and gave the `main-content` division a different block.

HTML

```
<div id="image-container">

    <div id="form"><input type="text" /></div>

</div>

<div id="main-content"><p>this is a a test</p></div>
```

CSS:

```
#image-container {

    background: url(http://www.noao.edu/image_gallery/images/d4/androa.jpg);
    background-size: cover;
    padding: 6em 3em 6em 3em;

}
```

You can tweak the `padding` and some other attributes to get the desired effect. :)

> EDIT: According to the OP

You have given the image a property of `absolute`. Now, you need to know that when you give it an attribute of `absolute`, it is removed from the document flow and is not treated as a block-level element; and thus, you get the options to very precisely position and what not.

Now, since you want the `#main-content` to get it's own document block (flow), the best option (as mentioned by many fine coders here) is to remove the rule `img#image`; by doing this, you'll get the effect you want.

The reason here is very simple: you've removed the `input` from the document flow, and when you have the image there, it acts like the background; now, for elements to be on the next line (a block) you **need** to give the image a block of its own so that subsequent elements get rendered in new blocks.

I hope this explains the answer! :)

Comment: Thanks for the input. I have tried that method, but the issue is that i don't want to load image from CSS background property. I am trying to load the image from HTML document and position text and following paragraph accordingly. Kindly help.

Comment: @PrasantKumarRai, have a read at the edit. I have tried to explain you the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Remove `position: absolute` from `img` and give it `display:block`:

```
img#image {
   display: block; 
}
```

Demo:

https://jsfiddle.net/tp82y04n/1/